Resx Web Beacon Issue
When I run my project, it gives 46 of these errors. .resx extension and
Error The file DefinitionForms\defCity.resx could not be processed because it is on the Internet or in a Restricted zone, or the file has a web beacon. If you want to process these files, remove the web beacons.
Severity Level Code Description Project File Line Hiding Status
Error The file usrPhone.resx could not be processed because it is on the Internet or in a Restricted zone, or the file has a web beacon. Remove web beacons if you want to process these files. usrPhone
Error The file usrBlackList.resx could not be processed because it is on the Internet or in a Restricted zone, or the file has a web beacon. Remove web beacons if you want to process these files. PhoneListForms
Error The file Reports\frmReportSmokingHistory.resx could not be processed because it is on the Internet or in a Restricted zone, or the file has a web beacon. Remove web beacons if you want to process these files.
Error Reports\frmReportQuitPlanCallsStatisticsByPlanDate.resx could not be processed because it is on the Internet or in a Restricted zone, or the file has a web beacon. If you want to process these files, remove the web beacons.
Error The file Reports\frmReportQuitPlanCallsStatistics.resx could not be processed because it is on the Internet or in a Restricted zone, or the file has a web beacon. If you want to process these files, remove the web beacons.
running the application

If there is any mistake, please warn me first. I really need the solution

None of the answers given so far are valid and are long ago. Also I couldn't find the solution.
